# Pointer as a structure variable in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When I use code like this :

```
typedef struct {
        int x;
        int *pInt;
} tData;

tData *ptData = malloc(sizeof(tData));
```

If i understand it right, i allocated memory with size of `tData` and returned adress to this allocated memory to pointer `*ptData`.

But what if i used this code :

```
typedef struct {
        int x;
        int *pInt;
} *tData;
```

If I want to allocate memory to this struct, do I need a struct name? Because for me, if I allocate like `malloc(sizeof(*tData));`, it seems to me like I am allocating memory only for the pointer, not for the structure itself. When I want to refer to data in this structure, do I need to use pointer to pointer to a struct?
It confuses me a bit and I couldn't find the answer I am looking for.
Thank you for any explanation!

Comment: That's why don't typedef pointers!!

Comment: Some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). Apparently you should only typedef pointers like this "if your code will never dereference the pointer,"

Comment: Closing as dupe, if this does not answer your question, let me know.

Comment: It didn't. They discussed there first form of code i posted. I have problem understanding the second one. And i can't avoid it, in this situation..

Comment: You can use a struct name as you mentioned, or you can typedef both the struct type and the pointer to struct type like this typedef struct { ... } tData, *ptData;

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the reason one should avoid creating type-aliases of pointers.

As for how to use it, instead of passing the *type* to the `sizeof` operator, use the *variable*. Like e.g.

```
typedef struct {
        int x;
        int *pInt;
} *tData;

tData ptData = malloc(sizeof *ptData);  // Allocate memory for one structure
```

Comment: And may i ask, if i would change it to `typedef struct data {...} *tData;`, would `struct data *pData;` mean the same as `tData pData;` ?

Comment: @SevO Yes it would.